# Return empty string "" from Python convenience function instead of 0x0

Tags: python, gdb

Returning the Python string `""` from a [gdb convenience function](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html)'s `invoke` method appears to produce a result of `0x0` instead of the expected `""`.

This is because `gdb.Value("")` yields `0x0`:

```
(gdb) python
>print(gdb.Value(""))
>end
0x0
```

which is what'll happen when a Python string is returned.

Is there any sensible way to get gdb to yield a `gdb.Value` for a `char[]` or `char*` that points to `\x00`, i.e. the string `""`?

Comment: Yes, `gdb.Value` can't handle empty strings. I also had to create workarounds for this before.

Comment: @ssbssa That's the thing, it *can* handle empty strings. You can use the 2-argument buffer and type constructor to assemble a `gdb.Value` with an empty string payload. It just  converts the empty string to a null pointer by default, which frankly seems like a bug. If you wanted a `(char*)0` wouldn't you create one, not a `""`?

Comment: With your workaround you get a `gdb.Value` of type `char [1]`, which is the same type you would get with `gdb.Value("a")`. So it's not really an empty string.

Comment: @ssbssa It is an empty string. An empty C string is a `char*` or `char[]` with at least one defined element, where the first (and possibly only) byte is `0x00`. A `char[0]` is meaningless, and is only sort-of supported as a hack for variable length arrays. Really, gdb's `gdb.Value("a")` should be a `char[2]` for C.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, I just wanted to explain why it currently can't handle empty strings, since it is excluding the null-termination byte. This should probably be reported as a gdb bug.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly isn't a *good* way, but the workaround I'm using for now is to construct my own raw `gdb.Value` from a buffer where I explicitly supply a `char[]` type (python3):

```py
(gdb) python print( gdb.Value(b'\x00', gdb.lookup_type('char').array(0) ) )
""
```

e.g. a gdb convenience function:

```py
class Indent(gdb.Function):
    """Generate a string of 'depth' spaces"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(Indent, self).__init__("indent")

    def invoke(self, depth):
        """https://stackoverflow.com/a/66757722/398670"""
        depth = int(depth)
        if (depth <= 0):
            return gdb.Value(b"\x00", gdb.lookup_type('char').array(0))
        else:
            return " " * int(depth)

Indent()
```

But surely this can't be the right way, so I'm hoping someone will come along with a better solution.

Comment: is there a reason you did not add this in the question?

Comment: @python_user Because it's a solution, albeit not an ideal solution, and a self-answered question will show up in searches as having a potential answer so it's more likely to help others.